# Filter function failing with blanks or multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my current data set I have a variable number of entries that are initially reformatted from a different dataset but typically there are 500+ entries and it varies each week. Each entry has an ID and 5 associated values: maximum, minimum, expected and 2 other values that aren't relevant to the function. I am trying to filter out values for which the maximum is atleast 2 less than the expected by doing this: =FILTER(D3:I1000,(F3:F1000+2<I3:I1000)) and this function fails if blanks are in the table but otherwise produces the desired outcome so I manually edit the range each week.

However, when I try to filter out blanks by changing the function to =FILTER(D3:I1000,(F3:F1000<>"")*(F3:F1000+2<I3:I1000)) it returns an error (#VALUE!). Also worth noting that if I do the desired filter in two separate filters / cells - first removing the blanks, then comparing the values then it works and I do not understand why this is the case.

I have also tried making the preformatted dataset use blanks with some simple IF statements but they still produce an error if not filtered out or if the blank filter is in the same function. Additionally I tried putting the filters in two functions within the same cell so it looked like FILTER(FILTER( but that failed too.

Edit to include data example:

```
ID  Min Max Avg Current Expected
one 0   17.36   16.64   16.3    10.7
two 0   16.16   15.42   14.99   11.51
three   0   14.54   13.24   11.43   10.97
four    0   12.72   10.54   10.9    10.8
five    0   11.12   9.4 9.8 10.39
six -0.2    10.84   7.35    5.53    11.67
seven   0   8   7.17    7.52    10.45
eight   0   6.91    0.04    0   11.31
nine
```

In this restricted example, the desired filter should return the data for "seven" and "eight" but but because of the required reformatting mentioned above, the ninth entry actually should be ="" for the entire row and instead of an empty cell and this seems to break the function.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to provide a data example **as text which can be copy/pasted** that reproduces your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by fails if there are blanks? Blank is treated as 0 so unless your Expected is 2 or less it will include those rows & treat blank as 0. Can you give the layout of your table? when I mock up a version and do FILTER(array, (criteria1)*(criteria2)) it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#VALUE` comes because you are trying to add `2` to an empty string `""`. Which returns an error.

Instead of `(F3:F1000<>"")*(F3:F1000+2<I3:I1000)` Do `IF(F3:F1000<>"",(F3:F1000+2<I3:I1000),0)`

```
=FILTER(D3:I1000,IF(F3:F1000<>"",(F3:F1000+2<I3:I1000),0))
```

[image]

Note that in E11:I11 I have `=""`.  They are not true blanks.  True Blank cells would not have this problem